# c# Clipboard returns null, but can't be empty

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am trying to get a link which was generated on click and pasted in my clipboard. I tried everything I could find. But I always recieve "null", even though when I paste the link manually in a notepad and what not, I get it.

I tried this code with every defined Dataformat, but everything returned null.

```
string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

Comment: Does the clipboard have the link? Can you paste it in the notepad, before the above code executes?

Comment: yes, I can paste it anywhere.

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject): _To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute._ Have you tried that?

Comment: What does `Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats(true)` give you?

Comment: I did not use that correctly. Now that I inserted the STAThreadAttribute to the correct place it does work.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you for your answer, I am sorry for adding my own, could you please make your comment the answer? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject): To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.

Example:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;  // Need this for console app
namespace ClipboardTest
{
    class Program
    {
        // Without this attribute, will get null
        [STAThreadAttribute]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var clipboardText = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(clipboardText);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex1)
            {
                // Handle error
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadStateException ex2)
            {
                // Will throw this when:
                // "The current thread is not in single-threaded apartment (STA) mode and the Application.MessageLoop property value is true."
                // Handle error
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException ex3)
            {
                // Will throw this if clipboard in use
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: omg THANKS, i'm trying to make a simple program to save and load clipboard's actions for programs and this has been the first problem... ty :D