# windows c# console app, try to use ms-interop.excel and clipboard, got some problem

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows, clipboard

What I want to do is to develop a windows console app which load a excel file, get specified range and export to a jpg/png image file.
I try to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and `Clipboard` to do this, but the copyPicture method which copy excel range to clipboard does not work.

I am using windows10, visual studio 2017, and all of the references what I "using" have been added in to my project.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1

{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        string str;
        int rCnt = 0;
        int cCnt = 0;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\testex.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range rg = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:B2"];
        rg.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);

        if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null) {
            IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();


            if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)) {

                Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
                image.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\testexcel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            }
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
}
}
```

In my code, everything can run.
But `Clipboard.GetDataObject()` got a null.

Comment: I suspect your call to `If (Clipboard.GetDataObject()` != null)` is removing the object. The proper code would be `IDataObject data = ` followed by `if (data != null)`. There's no need for two separate calls to retrieve the data object.

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, it's not. I change my code, do this `IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();` firstly, and then do this `if (data != null) {`, the condition still get false. Also, I try to paste the clipboard in other rich text editior(which can paste picture), I can see the range which I copied.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the reason is that I missed this `STAThreadAttribute`.

After added this:

```
{
class Program
{
    STAThreadAttribute
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // things about clipboard
    }
}
```

The problem has been resolved.

Thanks for [c# Clipboard returns null, but can't be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444458/c-sharp-clipboard-returns-null-but-cant-be-empty/51445094#51445094).